# ZF2 dependency form not getting fields from fieldset

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I am trying to build a form via the ZF2 FormElementManager and have followed examples on the web, including Zend's own instructions here:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html

Module.php

```
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\FormElementProviderInterface;
use Application\Form\PlayerFieldset;

class Module implements FormElementProviderInterface
{
    public function getFormElementConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'PlayerFieldset' => function ($sm) {
                    return new Form\PlayerFieldset();
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

IndexController.php

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $formManager = $sm->get('FormElementManager');
        $form = $formManager->get('Application\Form\PlayerForm');

        $formViewObj = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
        $formViewObj->setTemplate('application/widgets/form.phtml');
        return $formViewObj;
    }
}
```

PlayerForm.php

```
use Zend\Form\Form;

class PlayerForm extends Form
{
    public function init()
    {               
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'playerdetails',
            'type' => 'PlayerFieldset',
        ));
    }
}
```

PlayerFieldset.php

```
class PlayerFieldset extends Fieldset implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{   
    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function init()
    {       
        parent::__construct('Player');
        $this->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(false))
            ->setObject(new Player());
        $sm = $this->getFormFactory()->getFormElementManager()->getServiceLocator();
        $msi = $sm->get('MyServiceInterface');
        $elements = $msi->request('FieldManager','getFieldsByEntity','Player');

        // Add fields to fieldset
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $this->add($element);
        }                       
    }
}
```

At the end of `PlayerFieldset.php`, the elements have been added to `$this` (I can see this by doing a call to `$this->getElements();` and printing out the result.

However, back in `IndexController.php` the `$form` object does not have my elements attached to it.

Can Anyone help me explain why?

Comment: Do you get any errors? `$sm` is not defined in `indexAction()` you would need to add `$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();` to the top of that method. Also the **form** wont have the elements the **fieldset** will - `$form->get('playerdetails')->getElements()`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The `$sm` was defined in the `indexAction()` but I'd not posted it. The method to get the elements from my `playerdetails` was the solution - thank you!

Comment: Great, I've added my answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *form* wont have the elements the *fieldset* will

So rather than the forms elements :

```
$form->getElements();
```

You would need to be first fetching the `playerdetails` fieldset and then returning it's elements.

```
$form->get('playerdetails')->getElements();
```